# Audit columns - join or copy?

Tags: audit, database-normalization

I have seen many business systems not using joins on Users table but instead copying user name (or firstname+lastname) to a CreatedBy audit field.

I already see one issue with this approach - a user might marry and change her last name, and then CreatedBy field will keep the old value.

Is there any good reason why to draw back from data normalization and create redundant text data for the CreatedBy field?

Answer (score 0):

Storing someone's name without using a foreign key reference lets you delete users without affecting information about which rows they created. Whether this is wise is application-dependent.

In most organizations, if it's important to know what someone's name was 3 years ago, there's some way to do it. It might not be in the database. It might be, "Go ask Jerry in HR. He remembers everyone."  Whether *this* is wise is also application-dependent.

In any case, this doesn't necessarily violate any guidelines of normalization. In the one case, you're storing the current name or the preferred name of a user. In the other case, you're storing the name of a user at the time the row was created, and that still constitutes a true fact.